# Merging all elements in the 2nd column with the same element in 1st column

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working on a protein annotation data. Below, you can see the example input data frame:

```
 UNIPROT          CLASS_TERM
 A6NDV4           cell adhesion molecule
 O00186           membrane traffic protein
 O00186           membrane trafficking regulatory protein
 O00186           transporter
 O00401           actin family cytoskeletal protein
 O00401           cytoskeletal protein
 O00422           DNA binding protein
 O00422           chromatin/chromatin-binding protein
 O00422           nucleic acid binding
```

What I want to do is that creating another data frame with two columns (1st col: UNIPROT, 2nd: CLASS_TERM) again. However, I want to merge all values in the 2nd column belonging to the same UNIPROT value.

Here is a short example for desired output:

```
UNIPROT                          CLASS_TERM
 A6NDV4                          cell adhesion molecule
 O00186                          membrane traffic protein;membrane trafficking regulatory;transporter protein
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Best,

Answer (score 0):

We can use `aggregate` from `base R` in a single line

```
aggregate(CLASS_TERM ~ UNIPROT, df1, paste, collapse = ';')
```

-output

```
# UNIPROT                                                                   CLASS_TERM
#1  A6NDV4                                                       cell adhesion molecule
#2  O00186 membrane traffic protein;membrane trafficking regulatory protein;transporter
#3  O00401                       actin family cytoskeletal protein;cytoskeletal protein
#4  O00422 DNA binding protein;chromatin/chromatin-binding protein;nucleic acid binding
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(UNIPROT) %>%
   summarise(CLASS_TERM = str_c(CLASS_TERM, collapse=";"), .groups = 'drop')
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(UNIPROT = c("A6NDV4", "O00186", "O00186", "O00186", 
"O00401", "O00401", "O00422", "O00422", "O00422"), CLASS_TERM = c("cell adhesion molecule", 
"membrane traffic protein", "membrane trafficking regulatory protein", 
"transporter", "actin family cytoskeletal protein", "cytoskeletal protein", 
"DNA binding protein", "chromatin/chromatin-binding protein", 
"nucleic acid binding")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `toString` in this way:

```
#Code
res <- aggregate(CLASS_TERM~UNIPROT,df,function(x) toString(x,sep=';'))
res$CLASS_TERM <- gsub(', ',';',res$CLASS_TERM)
```

Output:

```
res
  UNIPROT                                                                   CLASS_TERM
1  A6NDV4                                                       cell adhesion molecule
2  O00186 membrane traffic protein;membrane trafficking regulatory protein;transporter
3  O00401                       actin family cytoskeletal protein;cytoskeletal protein
4  O00422 DNA binding protein;chromatin/chromatin-binding protein;nucleic acid binding
```